# Is there something for function composition in <functional>?

Tags: c++, stl, bind, predicate

What I want to do is done pretty easily with C++0x lambdas. I just want to figure out how to do it with `bind1st` and `bind2nd` only.

I need to find the first element `i` in the vector `v`, such that `(i-1)/p1 == p2` where p1 and p2 are predefined integers.

```
find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), ???)
```

I can't figure out how to form the predicate with `minus<int>` `divides<int>` `equal_to<int>` and `bind2nd`. Seems like I need some function composition

```
equal(div(minus(i, 1), p1), p2)
```

Is it possible?

Please don't suggest workarounds such as writing a freestanding unary function or a struct with `operator()`. I am really interested in mechanics of functors in functional along with `bind1st`  and `bind2nd`. This is not for real code, just interest. Thanks :)

Comment: I've never seen the word superposition used like that. Do you use it to mean function composition?

Comment: @interjay: Yes, I do. Isn't the term superposition used in English?:( I'll have to edit

Comment: Looks like you can't do `bind1st(bind2nd(...), ...);`. [My poor attempt at variadic templates](http://ideone.com/mqNEp). It's in a different direction than in maths, but what the hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to do is not possible with only the current `functional` library. You would need to create your own class or function to do the composition.

Boost used to offer a Compose library that was used to compose functions like this, but I think it was removed when Bind and Lambda were introduced.

And just for the sake of completion, it can be done with `bind` using something like:

```
std::bind(std::equal_to<int>(), /* ... == P2 */
    std::bind(std::divides<int>(), /* ... / P1 == P2 */
        std::bind(std::minus<int>(), _1, 1), /* (x - 1) / P1 == P2 */
    p1), 
p2);
```

Comment: Thank God for lambdas in C++0x!

Answer (score 0):

If you can pull up `i` on the left hand side of equation then you don't need to compose altogether i guess. `i.e. i == p1*p2+1`.

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <functional>
  3 #include <algorithm>
  4 #include <vector>
  5 using namespace std;
  6 
  7 int main ()
  8 {
  9 
 10     vector<int> numbers;
 11     for(int i = 0;i< 10;i++) {
 12        numbers.push_back(i+20);
 13     }
 14 
 15 int p1=4,p2=5;
 16 vector<int>::iterator iter;
 17 
 18 iter = find_if ( numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), bind2nd(equal_to<int>(),p1*p2+1));
 19 cout << "The number is "<< *iter <<"\n";
 20 return 0;
 21 }
```

But if you insist on composing the way your expression is then @dauphic's answer is the one to go for.

Comment: I know that, the thing is that `(i-1)/p1 == p2` is not equivalent to `i==p1*p2+1` because division is integer division :)